# how to change only text in a wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, arabic, right-to-left, left-to-right

i want to change the text inside my wordpress theme from LTR to RTL,

```
<html dir="RTL">
```

i implemented this code into header.php, it makes a mirror of the whole website such as images,buttons etc.. i just want to change the text alignment inside the buttons without changing the button position.

i also tried the following code:

```
   text-align: left;
   float: right;
   clear: left;
```

changed "left to "right" and the opposite but it changed the whole website elements and text, i only want to change the text.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `dir="RTL"` (otherwise all the items will be displayed from RTL)
2. Use `direction:rtl;` for the button in your Stylesheet to display the item in right-to-left.